# Как получить доступ к переменной из функции?

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть простейшая игра на Python + Tkinter. Это кликер монет. Но проблема заключается вот в чём: у меня есть переменная, отвечающая за кол-во монет и переменная, отвечающая за прибавление монет за один клик по кнопке. Функция `output` прибавляет к текущему количеству монет ещё одну. Когда я пытаюсь вывести кол-во монет выскакивает ошибка `local variable 'money' referenced before assignment`. Сделав переменную глобальной, ошибка начинает гласить, что якобы она и так уже глобальная. Логика? Не думаю. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

money = 0
money_in_click = 1

def output(event):
money += money_in_click

root = Tk()
root.title("Money Click v1.0")
root.geometry('700x440')

button = Button(root, text="Жми!", bg='lightgreen', fg='black')
button.pack()
label_money = Label(root, text="Ваши монеты: " + str(money), bg='yellow', fg='black')
label_money.pack(side=TOP)

button.bind("<Button-1>", output)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Кстати, если я вообще уберу переменные с начала кода, просто будет писаться "name 'money' is not defined". Может я тупой начинающий питонист, а может это и ошибка века =D.

Comment: А тут код "как есть" или все таки виджет отображения кода "съел" все табы? Прост по-хорошему после def output должны быть табы , чтобы "определить" где тело функции

Comment: @alexoander тут весь код, как есть.

Comment: Тогда ваша ошибка вам явно намекает что def(output): определен неверно. Точнее тело функции получается или пустое, или все что написано ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама ошибка заключается в том, что она падает не при попытке вывода (`str(money`), а при попытке вызвать функцию `output`.

Внутри функции output нет никакого способа получить доступ к money извне. И т.к. `money+=money_in_click` это тоже самое что и `money = money + money_in_click` , то ошибка намекает, что `money` не проиницализирована, для того чтобы ее можно было присваивать (даже если это присвоение ее самой).

Update: пример кода (не советую так писать - для правильного доступа к переменным лучше создавать классы с полями/свойствами)

```
money = 0
money_in_click = 1

def output():
    global money
    money+=money_in_click

output()
output()
output()
print(money)
```

Comment: А всё-таки как решить проблему?

Comment: как её проиницализировать?

Comment: @vaytonqueen добавил код - тут дело в том, что надо заставить функцию узнать о том что money глобальная переменная и то что мы хотим ее изменить. Это плохой способ - для этого всего есть более правильный подход - создание классов и полей/свойств класса